# How to fail the mvc controller on purpose and do nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, controller, telerik

Controller Method:

```
    public ActionResult GetCustomerComments([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string invoices)
    {
        if (invoices != "fail")
        {
            List<JNI.Enterprise.Contracts.CustomerComments> customer = InvoiceService.GetCustomerComments(invoices);

            return Json(customer.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
        else
        {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
```

I am trying to upgrade the grid using ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: webManager.resolveUrl("~/maint/GetCustomerComments"),
    method: "POST",
    data: { invoices: invoicesList },
    success: function () {
        var grid = $('#CustomerCommentsGrid').data('kendoGrid');
        grid.dataSource.read();
        grid.refresh();
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('an error occurred');
    }
});
```

But the problem is Grid is called again and I want to stop that.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<CustomerComments>()
  .Name("CustomerCommentsGrid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(i => i.INVOICE).Title("Invoice").Width(15);
      columns.Bound(i => i.Comment).Title("Comment").Width(40);

  }).Pageable(pageable => pageable
      .Refresh(true)
  )
  .Scrollable()
  .Sortable()
  .Filterable()
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
      .Ajax().UseJniErrorHandler()
      .PageSize(10)
          .Read(read => read.Action("GetCustomerComments", "Maint", new { invoices = "fail" }))
  )
```

)

Comment: You need to reformulate your question....it is very unclear

Comment: are you trying to prevent the grid from loading automatically?  there's an AutoBind option  you can set to false

Comment: I was using using wrong logic ajax datasource grid.
I was using 

success: function () {
        var grid = $('#CustomerCommentsGrid').data('kendoGrid');
        grid.dataSource.read();
        grid.refresh();

instead of

success: function (result) {
            var grid = $("#CustomerCommentsGrid").data("kendoGrid");
            var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: result.Data
            });
            grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
            grid.dataSource.read();
        },

so I was asking not to bind it again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to avoid running the code in your success callback? If that's the case you can always change the response status code in your action to indicate something went wrong. Then the error callback in your ajax method will be called and you can handle any exception, if need be.

Example:

```
public ActionResult GetCustomerComments([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string invoices)
{
    if (invoices != "fail")
    {
        List<JNI.Enterprise.Contracts.CustomerComments> customer = InvoiceService.GetCustomerComments(invoices);
        return Json(customer.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
    else
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return Json("ERROR");
    }
}
```

and in your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
     url: webManager.resolveUrl("~/maint/GetCustomerComments"),
     method: "POST",
     data: { invoices: invoicesList },
     success: function () {
         var grid = $('#CustomerCommentsGrid').data('kendoGrid');
         grid.dataSource.read();
         grid.refresh();
     },
     error: function () {
         if (xhr.responseJSON == "ERROR") {
            alert('my handled error');
         }
         alert('an error occurred');
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No.
I am not sure if there is a solution to my original question but I was able to solve my problem by updating with following AJAX

```
    $.ajax({
        url: webManager.resolveUrl("~/maint/GetCustomerComments"),
        method: "POST",
        data: { invoices: invoicesList },
        success: function (result) {
            var grid = $("#CustomerCommentsGrid").data("kendoGrid");
            var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: result.Data
            });
            grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
            grid.dataSource.read();
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('an error occurred');
        }

    });
```